# "Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress" when using $apply for multiple actions occur at the same time

Tags: angularjs

Take a look at my code

```
$scope.update = function () {
    //remove empty row in list before update
    if ($scope.PatternData.length > 1) {
        removeEmptyRow($scope.PatternData);
    }

    if (!$scope.$$phase) {
        $scope.$apply();
    }
    $scope.$apply();

    //update data
    orderPatternService.updatePattern(function () {
        //reload datatable
        $scope.tableParams.reload();
        //display notification
        $timeout(function () {
            notifyService.popEdit();
        });
    },$scope.PatternData);
};
```

I want to `remove empty row in list before update` and `update data` actions to occur at the same time, so I put

```
if (!$scope.$$phase) {
        $scope.$apply();
    }
    $scope.$apply();
```

in between those two actions.

I have achieved my ideas without any influence, however, the `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress` error has occurred in the console

Please let me know the cause of this error

Comment: Using `$scope.$$phase` is a antipattern, have you considered promise chaining? Or simply call `$timeout()` after the action? It will call digest in the next tick, so it should work as expected.

Comment: hi Kamil, is it because I used `$scope.$$phase` before `$timeout()`?

Comment: nope, see, my answer, I will expand it if it is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably error in the code:

```
if (!$scope.$$phase) { // If you are controlling the digest phase like this,
    $scope.$apply();
}
$scope.$apply(); // then this line is not necessary!
```

Comment: If I remove `$scope.$apply();`, `remove empty row in list before update` and `update data` actions will not happen at the same time

Comment: Digest cycle is run by AngularJs automatically. Your `IF` means: "If the digest cycle is NOT running, then run it manually". But after your `IF` you are calling it anyhow. And that's why the error appears. So you calling the digest cycle at least 2 and sometimes 3 times.

Comment: There is not anything like `same time` in javascript because it is single threaded. You are using asynchronous calls and the best way to handle in predictably is `promise chaining`, try to google it and understand how it works. It will help you a lot.

Comment: If you need any further advice, feel free to ask.

Comment: hi Kamil, can I ask you another question?

Comment: Do you know how to configure IISManager to run localhost:3000?